# Modem connected via USB: sniffing of "AT commands" possible?

Tags: usb, modem, sniffing

can somebody confirm if I can use USB sniffing to capture the "AT commands" sent to an HSDPA modem from an external application?

Comment: For USB software snooping I can recommend http://usbsnoop.sourceforge.net/ (i.e if you are on the Win32 platform).

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt is built into the Linux kernel

Answer (score 0):

In USB parliance, modems belong to the [Communications Device Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class).

I believe this class specifies use of AT commands (more correctly called [Hayes commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)) for supporting devices, so yes, you should be able to see the AT commands if you have a bus sniffer.